# In Verilog, when using a for-loop within a sequential process, how can you increment the sequential variable?

Tags: for-loop, verilog, sequential

Here is a snippet of code, hopefully you are alright without the preamble:

```
   always @ (posedge clk)
   begin
      if(rst)
      begin
         i<=0;
         j<=0;
      end
      else
      begin
         for(j = 0 ; j < 16 ; j = j+1)
         begin
            if(i<8)
            begin
               var[j] <= var_2[i];
               i <= i+1;
            end
         end      
      end
   end
```

Basically, I am wondering if the outer "for-loop" will erroneously increment the counter variable `i`, rather than simply calculating the 16 `var`s in parallel. If this is the case, should I cut the for-loop short so that the variable is incremented outside the for-loop?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are not sure what the code will do the normal procedure is to ***simulate***. I don't know what you **want** the code to do. Here it assigns all var[j] with var_2[i] if i<8. The increment of I does not happen until AFTER the clock.

Comment: Hi Oldfart (nice name lol :) )

I have simulated, and it does work in simulation.  However, synthesis is giving me errors.  That is why I'm asking! Also, I find that StackOverflow can give me extra information that I didn't even know I needed

Comment: What is your synthesis error? Probably something with multiple assignments to i as i is not initialised or set in any way here

Comment: Hi again Oldfart.  i is initialized to 0 at every "rst" signal. I just haven't written that part. I will edit it.

 I suppose this code is a little bit confusing, since I was just trying to convey the idea.  You're right that it doesn't make sense.  According to your answer though, you are saying, I think, that for the first 'for' iteration, var[15:0] = var_2[0], then for the next, var[15:0] = var_2[1], etc...

is that correct? Thanks!

Also, the synthesis error are timing errors, apparently.  I am operating on a large number of bits, but I don't think it is anything astronomical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making the code unnecessary complex.

If i<8 then these get executed:

```
var[j] <= var_2[i];
i <= i+1;
```

But the `i` is not incremented until **after** the clock edge.
As 'i' does not change the condition does not change and thus once true it stays true for all values of `j`.

Probably a better way of understanding this is to write the code as follows which has the exact same behavior:

```
   always @ (posedge clk)
   begin
      if(rst)
      begin
         i<=0;
         j<=0;
      end
      else
      begin
         for (j = 0 ; j < 16 ; j = j+1)
         begin
            if(i<8)
               var[j] <= var_2[i];
         end      
         // i increment independent from the 'j' loop
         if(i<8)
            i <= i+1;
      end
   end
```

Comment: Hi Oldfart, thanks for the answer.

So, it seems that my implementation wasn't necessarily *wrong*, but perhaps leaves a little too much to the imagination, unnecessarily (especially for people like me who are new to Verilog).  So, I suppose I need to look deeper into my code and figure out why I am getting the timing errors.  The actual code I am trying to implement is a parallel sorter that loops back its results to the input, to execute in log(x) time without using too many registers.

Comment: If I can add on to my parallel sorter idea, please let me know if it makes sense to you:

Consider 4, 32-bit variables, i.e., A[0], A[1], A[2], and A[3].  In parallel, I compare (1) A[0] with A[1] and (2) A[2] with A[3].  I put the results of (1) back into A[0] (if A[1]>A[0], then A[0] = A[1]).  I put the results of (2) back into A[1] (if A[3] > A[2], A[1] = A[3]).
Then, I run it again.  A[2] and A[3] are unchanged, but A[0] and A[1] should have the new maximum values, so that at the next cycle, A[0] has the maximum value.

Is this an efficient way to find the maximum value of A[0:3]?

Comment: You still have to compare A[1] with A[2]. have a look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/370467/how-to-write-a-for-generate-statement-to-generate-multiple-instances-of-this-par/370503?r=SearchResults&s=2|11.0874#370503)

Comment: I am not sure why I would need to compare A[1] with A[2].  I am not interested in ordering the registers, rather just obtaining the maximum value.  
If A[1] > A[0], then A[0] = A[1]; else, A[0] = A[0].
If A[3] > A[2], then A[1] = A[3]; else, A[1] = A[2].

Then I would compare again.  You don't think this would work so that A[0] gets the maximum value at the end of the next cycle?